# devtools::document() won't include useDyLib in NAMESPACE

Tags: r

I am sure I am missing something stupid, but despite several hours looking online  I have not been able to solve this problem.
I am trying to make a simple R package with Rcpp code. The two toy routines are

```
#'  rtest
#'
#' This function does nothing
#' @param  x  a vector of numbers
#' @return a vector of number
#' @export
#' @examples
#' rtest(1:5)

rtest <- function(x) {
  x^2-rtest_cpp(x)
}
```

and

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//' another routine that doesn't do much
//'
//' @param x a numeric vector
//' @return a numeric vector

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector rtest_cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  int k=x.size();
  NumericVector y(k);
  for(int i=0;i<k;++i) y[i]=x[i]*x[i];
  return y;
}
```

Also the DESCRIPTION file is

```
Package: Rtest
Title: Test package
Version: 1.0.0
Authors@R: 
    person("Wolfgang", "Rolke", , "wolfgang.rolke@upr.edu", role = c("aut", "cre"),
           comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0002-3514-726X"))
Description: Package to test various package problems.
License: GPL (>=2)
Encoding: UTF-8
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.2.1
LinkingTo: Rcpp
Imports:  Rcpp
Suggests: rmarkdown, knitr
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Now when I run devtools::document() I get the NAMESPACE file with export(rtest) but not the a parts

```
useDynLib(“Rtest”)
importFrom(Rcpp, sourceCpp)
```

and so when I build the project and run rtest I get the error message that _Rtest_rtest_cpp is not available.

I can add the usedDynLib .. manually to NAMESPACE and build the project and then everything works fine, but I would much rather have the NAMESPACE file created by document().

What am I missing?

Thanks Limey. I had seen and tried this advice before, however only to add the @useDynLib part, but not to also add the @importFrom. Now it works!

I have a follow-up question, though. This is not the first package I have written with both R and Rcpp code, and I never had this problem before. I also never added those lines to the R file headers, either. And yet devtools::document() created the correct NAMESPACE file anyway. So what else tells  devtools::document() to do the right thing? I once thought it was adding   "LinkingTo: Rcpp;Imports:  Rcpp" to DESCRIPTION , but apparently not.

Comment: Try adding `#' @useDynLib <yourpackagename>; #' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp` at the start of the R file that references your C++ functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Limey. I had seen and tried this advice before, however only to add the @useDynLib part, but not to also add the @importFrom. Now it works! In fact, from reading other things on the internet I created a separate file called extra.R in the R folder with the code

```
#' @useDynLib Rtestrolke
#' @importFrom Rcpp evalCpp
#' @exportPattern "^[[:alpha:]]+"
NULL
```

and that does the trick as well.

As I said in the part of the question added later, this just leaves the mystery why this is sometimes needed and sometimes not. Still don't know the answer to that.